# PHP or Javascript: no element found error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, element

I'm working on a project for school, I have to take data from a db (created on PhPMyAdmin) and create a graphic.
I use PHP for get the data and Javascript to create the graphic, but I found and error and I can't get rid of it: when i lunch my html file the graphic structure appears, but it's empty. If I check Firefox console I get the error: ‘no element found’ and it's refered to php file.

PHP code:

```
<?php
require("conf.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM straniera";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$i=0;
$valori = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $valori[$i]=$row['2011'];
    $i++;
}
return $valori;
?>
```

Javascript code that lunch php:

```
var d = $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                       url: 'try.php'
              });
graphic(d);
```

Comment: Your code needs to `echo` something not `return` it. However you can't just echo an array like this and expect it to work in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You should change 'return' to 'echo' in php code, and echo something wrapped as html.

```
<?php
require("conf.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM straniera";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$i=0;
$valori = "";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $valori.= "<li>".$row['2011'].</li>;
}
echo $valori;
?>
```

Ajax should be:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"try.php",
            success: function(data){
                    $("#somediv ul").html(data);
                }
            });
```